# Installed Google Cloud SDK but can't access gcloud

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, environment-variables, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to install the Google Cloud SDK on OSX and do this node.js tutorial (https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/hello-world) and keep running into a problem where the `gcloud` is not found. It might be just be something simple about setting in or where I'm in saving the file.

I've read a ton of other posts here but haven't been able to solve this problem. Here are all the steps/issues:

I already created a project in the dev console.

Install the cloud sdk

```
MacBook-Pro-2:~ nico$ curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
```

Then go through the process

```
Directory to extract under (this will create a directory google-cloud-sdk) (/Users/nico):

Do you want to help improve the Google Cloud SDK (Y/n)?  y

Modify profile to update your $PATH and enable bash completion? (Y/n)? y

Enter path to an rc file to update, or leave blank to use [/Users/nico/.bash_profile]:
```

Then I tried to authenticate:

```
MacBook-Pro-2:~ nico$ gcloud auth login
-bash: gcloud: command not found
```

Then I went into a cloud sdk bin directory

```
MacBook-Pro-2:~ nico$ cd google-cloud-sdk/bin
MacBook-Pro-2:bin nico$ ./gcloud auth login
```

Authentication was successful

```
 MacBook-Pro-2:bin nico$ ./gcloud config set project helloworld-project
```

Setting the project was successful

```
MacBook-Pro-2:bin nico$ ./gcloud components update app

ERROR: (gcloud.components.update) Your current working directory is inside the Cloud SDK install root: /Users/nico/google-cloud-sdk.  
In order to perform this update, run the command from outside of this directory.
```

So then I move out of that directory

```
 MacBook-Pro-2:test_project nico$ gcloud components update app
-bash: gcloud: command not found
```

And now it's not working, do I have to set gcloud somewhere so it can be access globally? How can I update it and access the gcloud command line tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my ~/.bash_profile menu I had an error, at the top I had this line:

```
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi source /Users/nico/.bash_profile
```

Which was throwing an error and messed with `gcloud`, the weird thing is that other command line variables worked fine with that error.

Once I removed that line `gcloud` worked fine.

Answer (score 15):

Looking at the output of the install tool:

```
Enter path to an rc file to update, or leave blank to use [/Users/nico/.bash_profile]:
```

... it appears that the install tool updated "/Users/nico/.bash_profile" whereas Mac OS X relies on "/Users/nico/.profile" for the configuration. Copy the changes to "/Users/nico/.bash_profile" over to "/Users/nico/.profile" and then close and restart the Terminal for the changes to take effect.

In the new shell, you can see if "gcloud" is defined using the command:

```
 which gcloud
```

It should output:

```
 /Users/nico/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud
```

If that doesn't work, then I'd recommend just updating your PATH manually. To do that, edit ~/.profile:

```
 nano ~/.profile
```

And then add the following line at the very end:

```
 export PATH="$HOME/google-cloud-sdk/bin:$PATH"
```

And restart your shell. Note that if you are using a shell other than the builtin Terminal, you may need to edit a different file (such as ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile for a custom BASH installation, and various other "rc" files for altnerative shells such as ZSH, CSH, etc.) to update your PATH variable.

If this is still not working, I'd suggest debugging by typing:

```
echo "$PATH"
```

... so that you can at least see what the current path is set to.

Comment: Thanks Michael! I tried `which gcloud` and nothing showed up, then I opened `nano ~/.profile` and added it (screen shot: http://www.screencast.com/t/bEssG5te4n) and hit ^O. I restarted terminal and still no luck. I also edited the `~/.bash_profile` and added the it there (screen shot: http://www.screencast.com/t/jkpNucYZ) but it's still not working.  Any ideas?

Comment: Dumb question, but did you save the change? (That is, if you do "cat ~/.profile", is the change still there?)

Comment: Yeah, I saved it. This is what it `MacBook-Pro-2:~ nico$ cat ~/.profile` and it returns
`export PATH="$HOME/google-cloud-sdk/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: Okay, that's very strange. What happens when you type echo "$PATH" or echo "$HOME"? And did you restart the Terminal between edits?

Answer (score 2):

I had modified my

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

and added one line to the end of it

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Then you can log out & logged in again or run:

`source ~/.bash_profile`

After you have added the line.

> OS: Linux vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 3.13.0-116-generic #163-Ubuntu

Or Simply Run:

```
echo "source ~/.bashrc" >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
which gcloud
```

Showed me

> /home/myusername/google/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud