# gcloud command not found -installing Google Cloud SDK

Tags: terminal, installation, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am trying to install the Google Cloud SDK on Mac using the following command in terminal

```
curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
```

It worked fine but when I move to the next step of

```
gcloud init
```

I get the following

> -bash: gcloud: command not found

I have tried all solutions to the same question as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037279/gcloud-command-not-found-while-installing-google-cloud-sdk), however I still get the same error message. The installer didn't prompt me with the following message either: `Modify profile to update your $PATH and enable bash completion? (Y/n)?`

Comment: Did you also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31084458/installed-google-cloud-sdk-but-cant-access-gcloud?

Comment: @jarmod I have just done. I followed every step with no success.  Echoing the path; `echo "$PATH"` results in `/Users/myname/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin`

Comment: Some ideas: you can easily read the install script at https://sdk.cloud.google.com. Did mktemp fail? Take a look at the install_google_cloud_sdk.bash script. Does it log progress anywhere? is there a log file you can read to see what failed? Did the gcloud binary itself get installed somewhere (use find/locate to search for it) and it's simply that your PATH has not been modified to find it?

Comment: So you've resolved the problem? If so, write that up as the answer and then accept it as the answer, otherwise people won't know that the problem has been solved.

Comment: @jarmod actually not yet. The above executed by mistake in a unix terminal and worked there but not yet in my local machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root cause of this is the Cloud SDK not being added to your path. If you followed the [multitude of other answers about this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=gcloud%20%22command%20not%20found%22) and still have the same problem, it means you missed a step.

You can edit `/Users/<yourname>/.profile` and either include the following lines:

```
# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
source '<path-to-where-you-installed-the-cloud-sdk>/path.bash.inc'
```

Or you can manually set your PATH variable:

```
export $PATH=<path-to-where-you-installed-the-cloud-sdk>:$PATH
```

Comment: This works fine only for first time, to use the `gcloud` command in new tab or in new window am getting the same error message "gcloud command not found". How to make the gcloud command available globally?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same trouble and put the sdk folder inside a folder with "-" in the path.
So I clean the $PATH and change the folder's location to my home. and its work